# Выровнять блок footer внизу под всем

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Не могу выровнять блок footer ниже всего, а выравниваеться по низу блока leftbar

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #22313a;
  /*height: 1000px;*/
}

.navigation {
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.navigation>div {
  background: #25252d;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  box-shadow: 1px 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.main {}

.item-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.item-container>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-container:hover {
  background: #1d1d27;
}

.item-container+.f-right+.active {
  background: #1d1d27;
}

.item-container+.f-right+.mail>a {
  color: #777777;
}

.f-right {
  float: right;
}

.left-bar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #2b3942;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.right-bar {
  width: 77%;
  /*background-color: #2b3942;*/
  /*height: 500px;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-item {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2b3942;
}

.disc {
  background-color: #2b3942;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: #2b3942;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item-container">
          <a href="index.html">
                    CLOUD-MINING-SERVICES.COM
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item-container f-right">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/eng.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item-container f-right active">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/rus.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item-container f-right mail">
          <a href="mailto:info@Cloud-Mining-Services.com">
                    info@Cloud-Mining-Services.com
                </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="bar left-bar mt-3">
      <p>Leftbar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bar right-bar f-right">
      <div class="container p-0">
        <div class="row mr-3">
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="w-100"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="card-item m-3 p-0 col-md"></div>
          <div class="w-100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container p-0">
        <div class="row mr-3">
          <div class="disc m-3 p-3 col">
            <h3>Decsription</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://webcareer.ru/clearfix-na-css.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитай тут или погугли  clearfix  https://webcareer.ru/clearfix-na-css.html в интернете много информации на эту тему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте ссылки в качестве дополнения к вашему ответу, а не вместо него. После изменения или удаления материалов по ссылке ваш ответ в нынешней редакции не будет иметь смысла.